# Caramel Coffee Mead

Tags: mead, brewing, beginner

I'm looking into brewing a mead in the near future. I have exactly 0 experience brewing anything. I'm going to buy a store-bought brewing kit in the next few weeks if everything lines up.

I'm wondering if anyone's ever made a Caramel Coffee Mead, and if so do you have a recipe, or any tips on how to make it work. I want at least an 8% ABV, but no more than 16%. I'm looking for it to be a fairly sweet drink.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to ask this question, feel free to delete if this isnt something that fits this stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard there are some honeys (carrot, goldenrod) that will give more caramel-like flavors - you could also try lightly boiling the honey to make your mead a bochet, which I'm told will create caramel flavors.

This site talks about honey varietals: https://gotmead.com/blog/making-mead/honey-table/
This site talks about the process of making a bochet more: https://homebrewsupply.com/learn/boiling-up-a-bochet.html

The only other thing I can think of is just making your own caramel at home and adding it right in, whether in the primary (aka right at the start) or in the secondary (aka after most of the fermenting's done).